# Do I need FCM to handle local notifications in React Native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a social-network like app in React Native and firebase which requires in-app notifications, something like a notification bell with a badge count that updates if a user likes or comments on one of your posts for example.

I recently started reading about FCM and similar tools but I am not sure if that is required/preferred for my use case. From my understanding, those are typically used for Push notifications, and I think that the in-app badge count can be handled using local context and queries to firestore.

In the future, I expect to have Push notifications as well for important alerts. Are those two things independent of each other? Can I manage in-app notification a certain way and use FCM for push notifications later, or will those eventually conflict? Would FCM handle all of the above use cases?

I couldn't find too many resources online. Whenever I search for react native notifications, I only get results about FCM and Push notifications.

Comment: For Android, I think so. Then you should even be able to hook into the fcm message to update your state

Comment: FCM notifications are primarily for marketing purposes. In case you need to push notifications when some changes happen. Try local based notification like Notifee - https://notifee.app/